# Detecting longer signals in a Short-Time Fourier Transform Output

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

I am executing a [Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) in Python on a live-stream of data that is being written to a text file, that is being read in.

I am trying to execute some alert if the signal on the right hand side of the image is detected.  For example, I am trying to effectively filter out the quick burst of frequencies, and only trigger an alert if a long event is detected.

`f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(data['Z'], fs=250, nperseg = 50)`

I am having trouble finding a way to filter the short bursts, and trigger an event if the longer set of frequencies is detected.

[image]

Median Filter:
`med_filter = scipy.signal.medfilt(np.abs(Zxx), 9)`
[image: With a Median Filter]

Comment: You could try a median filter with the right window length it should pretty much eliminate the short events.

Comment: Another approach could be to use a band-pass filter with a center frequency of around 60 to preprocess the input data and compute the short-time energy after filtering. To avoid short peaks, as @PaulPanzer noted, a [median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) or [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) filter could be worth an attempt. Furthermore, I think this question is better located at [the signal processing site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) than here at SO.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments.  I think the filtering will certainly help (I added a photo of the median filter above).  I posted the question here as well to get some tips on how to execute an event trigger like, `if( x length of the yellow area is greater than 20 steps) execute the event trigger`